# The number of soft 404 errors is increasing because of redirects to the home page

Tags: google-search-console, htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite, soft-404

I have an increase in soft 404 errors.

Using Apache in my `.htaccess` file I have:

```
Redirect 301 /test.html‎ /page/pop/test
Redirect 301 /about.html‎ /about
```

I have also tried:

```
Redirect 301 http://www.example.co.za/test.html‎ http://www.example.co.za/services/test
```

however whenever I go to:

```
http://www.example.co.za/test.html
http://www.example.co.za/about.html
```

it just redirects to the home page

I also have: `RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]` in `.htaccess`

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your attempts to get the syntax for your "Redirect 301" rules is correct.  The format should be:

```
Redirect 301 /relative-uri http://fully.qualified/url
```

So:

```
Redirect 301 /test.html‎ http://www.example.co.za/page/pop/test
Redirect 301 /about.html‎ http://www.example.co.za/about
```

As nathangiesbrecht says, your rewrite rule may also be interfering.

Comment: Tried this, it didn't work. I need the rewrite rule as the web project is using a framework so every request goes through `index.php`. Should i put it at the bottom rather?

Comment: The redirect rules should go first so that they happen first.

Answer (score 0):

The rule `RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L] in .htaccess` is redirecting all requests to your index.php page (home page). Remove that, and the rest of your redirects should work as expected.

Comment: Yes, all requests go `index.php` as the web project is using a framework, should I put it at the bottom rather